# How to selectively bold some but not all of an <a> element's link text rewritten by jQ function and injected into existing (loaded) page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current jQuery function snippet is as follows. It is updating some link text via Ajax so no page refresh is happening in the browser.

HTML before function executes:

```
<a href="..." id="count"><b>1</b> following</a>
```

My jQ function:

```
var counter = parseInt($('#count').text());
counter = counter + 1;
counter = counter.toString();
counter = counter.bold();
counter = counter + "following";             
$('#count').text(counter);
```

HTML after function executes:

```
<a href="..." id="count"><b>2</b> following</a>
```

The problem is I need the 2 to be bolded after my function increments it from 1 to 2. The first HTML snippet bolds the number **1** as the page is rendered. But because I'm using Ajax, I don't get a browser refresh so the `<b>` and `</b>` tags are shown as text vs. being used to bold **2**. Is there a way I can wrap that 2 to force the browser to bold it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace the entire chunk of text, only what is between your tags:

```
var counter = parseInt( $('#count').find("b").text() );
    counter++;

$("#count").find("b").text(counter);
```

I would actually use a styled `span` rather than `b` tags:

```
.following-counter {
    font-weight: bold;
}

<a href="..." id="count">
    <span class="following-counter">1</span>
    following
</a>
```

And the script:

```
var followingSpan = $("#count").find(".following-counter"),
    counter       = parseInt( followingSpan.text() );

counter++;

followingSpan.text(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first remove the `<b>` tag out of your html:

```
<a href="..." id="count">1 following</a>
```

Then, you could add your bold tags in your javascript:

```
var counter = parseInt($('#count').text());
counter = counter + 1;
counter = counter.toString();
counter = "<b>" + counter + "</b> following";             
$('#count').html(counter);
```

I removed the "Bold" javascript tag and just put it into the counter variable, then instead of `text`, changed it to `html`.

One thing I noticed is that you're getting the text and using `parseInt` to get rid of the word following?  I might put a `.split(" ")[0]` in there to get ONLY the number.

Also, to clean up your script:

```
var counter = parseInt($('#count').text().split(" ")[0]);
$('#count').html("<b>" + counter++ + "</b> following");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS, and save yourself the trouble:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
}

a::first-letter {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t6djV/).